# Iterating an array of arrays in AngularJS with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I've a serious problem with iterating an array (list) in AngularJS. 
The structure of the array is -> items{ var1, var2, array2[var3, var4] }. 
I want to display this array on a HTML page in a table with ng-repeat as follows:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
   <td >{{item.var1}}</td>
   <td >{{item.var2}}</td>
   <td ng-repeat="...">###</td>
</tr>
```

and in the place of "###" I need to display array2's variables after the right ng-repeat dercription, but I don't know the right syntax for this case. I have tried many solutions, but none of them was helpful.

Thanks for answers! :-)

Comment: you would just do `< td ng-repeat="subitem in item.array2">{{subitem}}< /td >`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had it right, it's as easy as nesting the `ng-repeat`, just use the first `ng-repeat`ed item's array property as the model for the nested one:

Try this, as I mentioned in my comment:

```
< td ng-repeat="subitem in item.array2">{{subitem}}< /td >
```

Answer (score 1):

Nested ng-repeats can lead to performance problems.  If the inner array is strings or numbers, consider using something like:

```
  <div ng-repeat="inner in outer">
         {{inner.join(',')}}
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code, here i refers to each nested array item in item.array2

```
      <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td >{{item.var1}}</td>
   <td >{{item.var2}}</td>
   <td ng-repeat="i in item.array2">{{i}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just iterate in `item.array2`, as you did in the first `ng-repeat`, something like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td >{{item.var1}}</td>
    <td >{{item.var2}}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="item_ in item.array2">
         {{item_}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have not tried, but it should work.